I have a problem with minting using a Candy Machine v3 + Sugar
I have a problem with minting using candy machine + sugar
I use:
Sugar https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/sugar/releases
Solana CLI
I successfully create a config file, do upload and deploy, and then test minting (like here: https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/sugar/getting-started)
/sugar2.7.1 upload       
[1/4]   Loading assets
Found 22 asset pair(s), uploading files:
+--------------------+
| images    |     22 |
| metadata  |     22 |
+--------------------+

[2/4]   Initializing upload
▪▪▪▪▪ Connected
Funding address:
  -> pubkey: 2A2*****(my wallet)
  -> lamports: 30533871 (◎ 0.030533871)
Signature: 5NT********
[3/4]  Uploading image files 

Sending data: (Ctrl+C to abort)
[00:00:09] Upload successful ███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 22/22

[4/4]  Uploading metadata files 

Sending data: (Ctrl+C to abort)
[00:00:00] Upload successful ███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 22/22

22/22 asset pair(s) uploaded.

✅ Command successful.

---

/sugar2.7.1 deploy       

[1/3]  Creating collection NFT for candy machine
Collection mint ID: 9fC*******

[2/3]  Creating candy machine
Candy machine ID: Dno*******

[3/3]  Writing config lines
Sending config line(s) in 2 transaction(s): (Ctrl+C to abort)
[00:00:01] Write config lines successful █████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 2/2

✅ Command successful.


Verification successful.
Test mint:
./sugar2.7.1 mint
[1/2]  Loading candy machine
Candy machine ID: Dno*********
▪▪▪▪▪ Done

[2/2]  Minting from candy machine

Minting to 2A2****** (my wallet)
▹▹▹▹▸ 21 item(s) remaining
Mint: F6y******
Signature: 5f******
Mint success

✅ Command successful.


Then I added guards:
Add + Update
Candy Guard ID: 8KYc*********************************
 :
 :.. base: 8PQ**********************
 :.. bump: 255
 :.. authority: 2A2***********(my wallet)
 :.. data: 
     :.. default: 
     :   :.. bot tax: none
     :   :.. sol payment: none
     :   :.. token payment: none
     :   :.. start date: none
     :   :.. third party signer: none
     :   :.. token gate: none
     :   :.. gatekeeper: none
     :   :.. end date: none
     :   :.. allow list: none
     :   :.. mint limit: 
     :   :   :.. id: 1
     :   :   :.. amount: 3
     :   :.. nft payment: none
     :   :.. redeemed amount: none
     :   :.. address gate: none
     :   :.. nft gate: none
     :   :.. nft burn: none
     :   :.. token burn: none
     :   :.. freeze sol payment: none
     :   :.. freeze token payment: none
     :   :.. program gate: none
     :   :.. allocation: none
     :   :.. token2022 payment: none
     :
     :.. groups: 
          :.. label: Public
              :.. bot tax: none
              :.. sol payment: none
              :.. token payment: none
              :.. start date: 
              :   :.. date: Fri April 19 2024 19:00:00 UTC
              :.. third party signer: none
              :.. token gate: none
              :.. gatekeeper: none
              :.. end date: none
              :.. allow list: none
              :.. mint limit: none
              :.. nft payment: none
              :.. redeemed amount: none
              :.. address gate: none
              :.. nft gate: none
              :.. nft burn: none
              :.. token burn: none
              :.. freeze sol payment: none
              :.. freeze token payment: none
              :.. program gate: none
              :.. allocation: none
              :.. token2022 payment: none

And after that I can't mint:
/sugar2.7.1 mint      
[1/2]  Loading candy machine
Candy machine ID: Dno***********
▪▪▪▪▪ Done

[2/2]  Minting from candy machine

Minting to 2A2****(my wallet)
▪▪▪▪▪ Mint failed 

 Error running command (re-run needed): Payer is not the Candy Machine mint authority, mint disallowed.

I get this error even if in config.json guards will look like this:
...
  "guards": {
  }
...

but if I do ./sugar guards remove, then I'll be able to mint.
candy machine info:
/sugar2.7.1 show
[1/1]  Looking up candy machine

 Candy machine ID: Dno*******
 :
 :.. authority: 2A2******
 :.. mint authority: 8KY*****
 :.. collection mint: 9fC*****
 :.. account version: V2
 :.. token standard: NonFungible
 :.. features: none
 :.. max supply: 0
 :.. items redeemed: 1
 :.. items available: 21
 :.. symbol: ******
 :.. seller fee basis points: 15% (1500)
 :.. is mutable: true
 :.. creators: 
 :   :.. 1: 2A2******* (100%)
 :.. hidden settings: none
 :.. config line settings: 
     :.. prefix_name: ****** 
     :.. name_length: 2
     :.. prefix_uri: https://arweave.net/
     :.. uri_length: 43
     :.. is_sequential: false

✅ Command successful.


I also can't minting using the candy machine UI
What am I doing wrong?
I hope someone will help me...
Have a nice day!
I have already described all this above, I hope it will not cause a big problem for the moderators

You can't mint using solana cli on your candy machine added candy guard.
But you can integrate website for your candy machine added candy guard.
And you can't mint NFT on the web integrating with candy machine which is not added candy guard.
